# Place carousel/navigation arrows outside the vue-awesome-slider

Tags: vue.js, carousel, swiper.js

I'm using Vue-awesome-slider as a carousel library and wanted to place swipe arrows outside the carousel body. But since the carousel container has overflow-hidden, i'm not able to place it outside the carousel.

https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper

Comment: I know it's too late to answer this question. But I placed my answer as I was searching for it and couldn't find a solution. As a researches I have done, I added my answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

just add to swiperOptions
`navigation: { nextEl: '.swiper-button-prev', prevEl: '.swiper-button-next', }`

Answer (score -2):

Just move the buttons elements outside the swiper-container.

```
<div>
  <swiper :options="swiperOption">
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 4</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this? This is not working and please make sure to try the solution first before you post it